# Set global thousand separator on knitr

Tags: r, formatting, format, knitr

I want all the numbers on my knitr report to be formatted as such by default:

```
format(num, digits = 2, big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",")
```

Defaulting the number of digits to 2 and the decimal mark to comma is easy, I just need to set `options(digits = 2, OutDec = ",")` in my first R chunk. However, I don't see how I can set the thousand separator to `" "` (or anything else, for that matter) in that format. I've also tried tweaking `opts_chunk`, but can't get it to work.

Of course, I'm trying to avoid having to insert `format()` inside every output, inline or otherwise. More intelligent formatting is one thing that drove me towards knitr from Sweave, after all.

How can I set default thousand separator marks on knitr?

Comment: This seems to be the answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/knitr/CnFwvk1Qn1E/WY-Xhf7Ph3AJ I haven't started using knitr yet, myself.

Comment: @agstudy good one, duly edited.

Comment: @Frank, that seems to solve the problem, although it's been giving me some weird results regarding rounding numbers. I'll see about tweaking it a little, thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As Frank noted, setting a knitr hook such as the following solves the problem:

```
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  prettyNum(x, big.mark=" ")
})
```

It turns out knitr hooks are a great way to tweak the output of R chunks on knitr. It's really worth it to take a look at http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks.

Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/knitr/CnFwvk1Qn1E/WY-Xhf7Ph3AJ

Comment: Is there a working example how to embed the knit hook in the output?

Comment: how can I do the same (simple) hook for plot markings?

Comment: And for embedded tables?

Comment: It's worth noting that this function expects the output of all inline code to be numeric, which may not be the case in an Rmarkdown document. Non-numeric inline output will then cause the document to fail to compile.

One can get around this by adapting the function slightly:
`knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
  if(!is.numeric(x)){
    x
  }else{
   prettyNum(round(x,2), big.mark=",") 
  }
})`