# R Markdown Table 1000 separator

Tags: r-markdown

I am trying to publish a table with 1000 separators and I am not having any luck with it. I followed the link here: [Set global thousand separator on knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965637/set-global-thousand-separator-on-knitr) but am not having much success.

My sample dataset is here: https://goo.gl/G7sZhr

The RMarkdown code is here:

```
---
title: "Table Example"
author: "Krishnan Viswanathan"
date: "August 4, 2015"
output: html_document
---
```

**Load Data**

`{r, results='asis', message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
   load("i75_from_flow.RData")
   library(data.table)`

`{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE,message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
   i75_from_flow <- i75_from_flow[order(-Tons),]
   knitr::kable(i75_from_flow)`

However, when I include this chunk of code **(knit_hook$set)** in the RMarkdown document, i get errors.

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE,message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}
i75_from_flow <- i75_from_flow[order(-Tons),]
knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
prettyNum(x, big.mark=",")
})
knitr::kable(i75_from_flow)
```
````

**Error:**

```
# object knit_hooks not found.
```

Any insights on what I am doing wrong and how to fix this is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Krishnan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about using `pander` with bunch of options to fine-tune your [markdown table](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#markdown-tables):

```
> pander::pander(i75_from_flow, big.mark = ',')

----------------------------
 ORIGFIPS   TERMFIPS   Tons 
---------- ---------- ------
  12,023     12,117   5,891 

  12,119     12,105   4,959 

  12,001     12,057   3,585 

  12,001     12,113   3,083 

  12,047     12,047   1,517 
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 25):

The easiest is to use the format arguments of the `kable()` function itself, where you can specify the big number mark like so:

```
kable(df, format.args = list(big.mark = ","))
```

So your example would look like:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE,message = FALSE, tidy=TRUE}

i75_from_flow <- i75_from_flow[order(-Tons),]
knitr::kable(i75_from_flow, format.args = list(big.mark = ","))
```
````

without any need for knitr hooks.

Answer (score 4):

The reason that the knit_hooks object is not found is that you either need to load the `knitr` package or use the `knitr::` prefix in order to set the `knit_hooks` options. For example:

```
knitr::knit_hooks$set(inline = function(x) {
prettyNum(x, big.mark=",")
})
```