# R notebook: opts_chunk$set doesn't work

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

I'm trying to set `echo=FALSE` as a default chunk option, but `opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)` doesn't work for notebook output.

Take this `.Rmd` file, for a regular R Markdown doc

````
---
title: "Problem with opts_chunk in html_notebook"
output: html_document
---

Set my options in this chunk:
```{r setup}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

Chunk 1
```{r echo=FALSE}
cat("Is the code echoed?")
```

Chunk 2
```{r}
cat("Chunk 2. Is the code echoed?")
```
````

I would expect both the chunks after the setup chunk to execute without echoing the code. With `output: html_document`, that's what I get:

[image: html_document_good]

But if I change the output line to `output: html_notebook`, I get the following

[image: html_notebook_bad]

There's another question here ([R notebook: opts_chunk has no effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186677/r-notebook-opts-chunk-has-no-effect)) with maybe the same issue, but it's not focused on `echo = FALSE`, and also it has no answers.

Comment: This appears to be a bug of some kind in RStudio's notebook generation -- I'll file a bug on the RStudio side and we'll take a look.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem? I'm having similar issues.

Comment: Sadly no. Still a problem for me with R Studio for OS X, Version 1.1.374